# Updating Highcharts series live data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

I am stuck trying to plot live data with highcharts in Swift / iOS. This is the current situation:

I append one value for each frame which is received from the internal microphone to an Array. The Array has a fixed size (it works like a FIFO).

Now I want a Highcharts line Plot to show all points inside my Array, updating each time there is a new audioframe received. I think the `.redraw` function should be doing this.

This is how the code looks like at the moment:
Setup of the lineplot inside the `Audioprocessing` class:

```
let options = HIOptions()
public var chartView = HIChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
let chart = HIChart()
let series = HISeries()

public func initChartView(view: UIView){
    // initialize Highcharts object
    chartView = HIChartView(frame: CGRect(x: view.bounds.origin.x, y: view.bounds.origin.y, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: (view.bounds.size.height - 50)))
    
    chart.type = "spline"
    options.chart = chart
    
    let title = HITitle()
    title.text = "Tonhoehe"
    options.title = title
    
    let xAxis = HIXAxis()
    xAxis.tickInterval = 1
    xAxis.type = "linear"
    xAxis.title = HITitle()
    xAxis.title.text = "Zeit [s]"
    options.xAxis = [xAxis]
    
    let yAxis = HIYAxis()
    yAxis.type = "logarithmic"
    yAxis.minorTickInterval = 0.1
    yAxis.title = HITitle()
    yAxis.title.text = "Frequenz [Hz]"
    options.yAxis = [yAxis]
    
    series.data = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
    series.showInLegend = false
    options.series = [series]
    
    chartView.options = options
    
}
```

in the function `processData()` I update the Array (which is called `data`), but I cannot update the Highcharts plot:

```
...
// updating the array
data.append(maxFrequency ?? 0)
if(data.count >= 500){
     data.removeFirst()
}
let newSeries = HISeries()
        newSeries.data = data
        self.chartView.options.series = [newSeries]// this was recommended on github but does not work at all
```

This will compile successfully but when I run the program it crashes with this error:

```
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[WKWebView evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:]
PID: 18985, TID: 1972086, Thread name: (none), Queue name: captureQueue, QoS: 25
Backtrace:
4   Highcharts                          0x0000000102859258 -[HIChartView updateOptions] + 344
5   Highcharts                          0x0000000102859830 -[HIChartView observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 148
6   Foundation                          0x00000001a47d9320 A0089247-6F38-3097-B144-F5E2C90ADD3A + 373536
7   Foundation                          0x00000001a487b0a4 A0089247-6F38-3097-B144-F5E2C90ADD3A + 1036452
8   Foundation                          0x00000001a487d4d8 A0089247-6F38-3097-B144-F5E2C90ADD3A + 1045720
9   Foundation                          0x00000001a487a8d0 A0089247-6F38-3097-B144-F5E2C90ADD3A + 1034448
10  Highcharts                          0x000000010282e674 -[HIChartsJSONSerializable updateArrayObject:newValue:propertyName:] + 452
11  Highcharts                          0x00000001027eae60 -[HIOptions setSeries:] + 108
```

I also tried  `.addPoint(HIDataPoint)` and `chartView.options.series[0].data = data` which also didn't work.

TL;DR:
How can I access the same functionality in Swift as the `.addPoint()` method in javascript to add data dynamically to a Highcharts chart?

The method proposed in https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios/issues/116 doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible to use the `chartView.addpoint(y)` method inside a `sessionQueue.async{}` thread. This was where I updated my inputData from the audio interface and where I tried to update the chart aswell.

Instead I created a `Timer` in `Viewcontroller` which calls the `chartView.addPoint(y)` method periodically. this works fine! Acquiring the audio data and updating the chart are now done separately.